# Show ERROR / Success messages after executes query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create an HTML form which I can enter MYSQL queries and run them via PHP. i use this code now i want to show  ERROR / Success messages  after executes query

```
 <?php   
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['query'])){ 
$query =  $_POST['query'];      
 mysql_query($query);

}

    ?> 

<form action="" method="post"> 
    <div> 
        <textarea name="query"></textarea> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" /> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand what exactly you are asking. Are you saying you want to create a form from which you could enter a query and then click the submit button to have that query executed? If so, just google html forms and PHP PDO, you should be able to put it together

Comment: By writing some PHP code.. Did you have any yet?

Comment: no i don't have yet but i really want to do that

Comment: Write a html form with an action="yourscript.php" and write your script in php :)

Comment: @SaggingRufus you right i exactly want to ask what you understand i had already tried google

Comment: @Curlas i want php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to run MySQL queries via user input? Just have the submit button redirect to a PHP script that grabs the user input(e.g $_REQUEST['query']) then connect to and query the database.
Code example:

PHP:

```
<?php

    /* query.php */
    $query = $_REQUEST['query']; //do SQLi prevention
    $conn  = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
    if($conn->connect_error) throw new \Exception('Failed to connect to MySQL server.'); //have the script handle the exception elsewhere
    if($conn->query($query) !== false)
    {
        echo 'Query executed successfully.';
    }
    else
    {
        throw new \Exception('MySQL error: ' . $conn->error); //have the script handle the exception elsewhere
    }
    $conn->close();
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <!-- index.html -->
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form method='POST' action='query.php'>
        <input type='text' name='query' />
        <br />
        <input type='submit' />
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```